# Writing to file advice

Tags: python, file-io

Here's my code:

```
import random

ch1=input("Please enter the name of your first character ")
strch1=(((random.randint(1,12)//(random.randint(1,4))))+10)
sklch1=(((random.randint(1,12)//(random.randint(1,4))))+10)
print("The strength value of "+ch1+" is:")
print (strch1)
print("and the skill value of "+ch1+" is:")
print (sklch1)

ch2=input("Please enter the name of your second character ")
strch2=(((random.randint(1,12)//(random.randint(1,4))))+10)
sklch2=(((random.randint(1,12)//(random.randint(1,4))))+10)
print("The strength value of "+ch2+" is:")
print (strch2)
print("and the skill value of "+ch2+" is:")
print (sklch2)

myFile = open("CharacterSkillAttributes.txt", "wt")

myFile.write("The attributes of "+ch1+" are: /n")
myFile.write("Strength: "+strch1+"/n")
myFile.write("Skill: "+sklch1+"/n")

myFile.write("The attributes of "+ch2+" are: /n")
myFile.write("Strength: "+strch2+"/n")
myFile.write("Skill: "+sklch2+"/n")

myFile.close()
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Computing Science\Computing science A453\Task 2\task 2 mostly working (needs 'save to file').py", line 22, in <module>
    myFile.write("Strength: "+strch1+"/n")
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I don't want to change the code too much (unless I really have to), just need this problem solved.

Comment: There is a difference between `"\n"` and `"/n"`. `"\n"` is the character for a newline.

Comment: Don't link to pastebin when asking questions.

Comment: sorry, i'm new here. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @Louis If my answer was helpful to you, would you mind accepting it by clicking the tick so it stays green? (After the grace period has passed of course). Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use string formatting to get rid of the error:

```
file.write('Strength: {0}\n'.format(sklch1))
```

Obviously you will have to do the same when you write to the file with `sklch2`.

Comment: Or more straighforwardly `print('Strength:', sklch1, file=file)`.  This way they don't have to worry about newlines *or* converting to a string!

Answer (score 1):

You should just make a string from your integer variable:

`myFile.write("Strength: " + str(strch1) + "/n")`

or as suggested Alex use `str.format()`.

Comment: Note that concatenation with `str()` is usually discouraged.

Comment: thank you very much, i'll try that and get back to you in a second

Comment: @Louis well, there is the one illustrated in my answer.

Comment: Actually Alex is right. `str.format()` is preferred.

Comment: It is to do with compatibility with other implementations of Python. It is also much cleaner.

Comment: also, what is the {0} there for?

Comment: @Louis It helps make it backwards compatible with Python 2.

Comment: personally I don't feel happy with using the format. part so I'm sticking with str, however when I run the code and the file is written, everything is on the same line. This is my code: http://pastebin.com/wByyxXvq   Sorry for being a pain in the ass.

Comment: @Louis Change all of the `'/n'` to `'\n'`, that is your mistake there. Newline characters need backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you exactly that, `strch1` is an int and you cannot concatenate it with string directly.

You can do

```
file.write('Strength: %s\n' % (sklch1))
```